# Django : is it possible to display multiple edit forms as one consolidated form in django admin?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have three **EDIT** forms, an environment has one or multiple machines, then a machine has one or multiple users. Now my question is there a way to display the three **EDIT** forms in one consolidated form with one save button. I want to display three tabs one for Environment and one for Machines (multiple) and one for Users (Multiple), Similar to this :

[image]

I have already achieved similar results using custom HTML template, but I'm not satisfied, it would be better if I got it done using Django admin configurations

my current solution :

````
                        <div class="tab-content mt-3" id="pills-tabContent">
                            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="environment" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="environment-tab">
                                <div class="step">
                                    <h2>Environment general information</h2>
                                   
                                    {% for field in environment_form %}
                                    <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                        {{ field.errors }}
                                        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                                        {% if field.help_text %}
                                        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="machine" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="machine-tab">
                                <div class="step">
                                    <h2>Machines information</h2>
                                    {% for machine_form in machine_forms %}
                                    <h3>Machine {{ forloop.counter }}</h3>
                                    {% for field in machine_form %}
                                    <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                        {{ field.errors }}
                                        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                                        {% if field.help_text %}
                                        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    {% if not forloop.last %}
                                    <hr>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="tab-pane fade" id="credentials" role="tabpanel"
                                aria-labelledby="credentials-tab">
                                <div class="step">
                                    <h2>Credentials information</h2>
                                    {% for credentials_form in credentials_forms %}
                                    <h3>Credentials {{ forloop.counter}}</h3>
                                     {% for field in credentials_form %}
                                    <div class="fieldWrapper">
                                        {{ field.errors }}
                                        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
                                        {% if field.help_text %}
                                        <p class="help">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</p>
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </div>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                    {% if not forloop.last %}
                                    <hr>
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% endfor %}
                                </div>
                            </div>



                            <div class="container mt-3">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
                            </div>
                        </div> ```
````